# Replicate Action Plan with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am wanting to create a template to use for a personal action plan. I googled around and found a format I like. I started to re-create this using TikZ, but I am not that familiar with the package. I want to create a template that looks like the image below (minus the text, I'll enter my own obviously), but I like the boxes and flow. Can anyone help me get started or give me some ideas on how to replicate this layout? Thanks so much![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMibw.png)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Well, I have the basic layout/structure made, but I hit an issue right away with making the "arrow box" that has the text "current skills" in it. Thus, I don't have much to show yet other than a blank document with a footer and some fonts. Maybe you can get me started with that "arrow box" and I can go from there.

Comment: With `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}`, you can do e.g. `\node[draw,signal, signal to=south, signal pointer angle=160, minimum width=3cm] {Stuff};` Edit: for the downward pointing ones. A right pointing one is easier: `\node[draw,signal] {Stuff};`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - What am I doing wrong? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.6in,landscape]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\node[draw,signal, signal to=south, signal pointer angle=160, minimum width=3cm]{Stuff}
\end{center}
\end{document}`

Comment: I get the following error: `Undefined control sequence \none....`

Comment: `\node` has to be inside a `tikzpicture` environment. And you need a semicolon at the end of it.

Comment: I think that's what I need help with - I've never used TikZ before - how would I go about doing the `tikzpicture` environment. I see it used, but I am not sure how to write that for what I am trying to draw...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nevermind - I was trying to make it harder than it needed to be. I've got it now! `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,signal, signal to=south, signal pointer angle=160, minimum width=3cm]{Stuff};
\node[draw,signal] {Stuff};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Torbjørn T. already showed you how to draw the signal nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473347/replicate-action-plan-with-tikz#comment1193775_473347). Other than that you can use a matrix. (Why `append after command` below does not work as expected, I do not know, but at least it creates the space needed to extend the arrows.) And please forgive me for not punching in the texts from your screenshot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,matrix,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
box/.style={draw,fill=green!20,align=center},
arr/.style={draw,fill=red!20,signal, signal to=south, signal pointer angle=160,
align=center}, % Torjorn
tbox/.style={draw,align=left},
sr/.style={signal,text width=1.8cm,align=left,alias=tmp,
append after command={(tmp.north east) -- ++ (0.2,0) -- ++(0.5,-0.5)
-- ++ (-0.5,-0.5) -- (tmp.south east)},draw=black}
]
 \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,column sep=2pt,row sep=3pt,nodes={text width=3cm,anchor=center,minimum height=1cm}]
 { |[sr,fill=green!20]| {Current\\ skills} & 
  |[box]| hupflbupfl & |[box]| hupflbupfl & 
  |[box]| hupflbupfl & |[box]| hupflbupfl \\
 |[sr,fill=red!20]| {Skills to\\ work on} & 
  |[arr]| hupflbupfl & |[arr]| hupflbupfl & 
  |[arr]| hupflbupfl & |[arr]| hupflbupfl \\
  & |[tbox]| {\begin{itemize}
   \item some item
   \item another item
   \item one more item
   \end{itemize}
   ~} 
  & |[tbox]| {\begin{itemize}
   \item some item
   \item another item
   \item one more item
   \end{itemize}
   ~} 
  & |[tbox]| {\begin{itemize}
   \item some item
   \item another item
   \item one more item
   \end{itemize}
   ~} 
  & |[tbox]| {\begin{itemize}
   \item some item
   \item another item
   \item one more item
   \end{itemize}
   ~} 
   \\
 };
 \foreach \X in {1,2}
 {\draw ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]mat-\X-1.north east) -- ++ (0.2,0) 
 -- ([xshift=2mm]mat-\X-1.east)
 -- ([xshift=2mm,yshift=\pgflinewidth/2]mat-\X-1.south east) -- ([yshift=\pgflinewidth/2]mat-\X-1.south east);
 }
 \path[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=blue]
 ([xshift=-2mm]mat-3-2.north west) --
 ([xshift=-1.5cm]mat-3-2.west) 
 node[circle,fill=blue!30,text=white,minimum size=1.4cm,align=center] {Goals}
 -- ([xshift=-2mm]mat-3-2.south west) -- cycle;
 \path (mat-1-1.south) -- (mat-2-1.north) coordinate[midway] (aux);
 \draw[dashed] (mat.west |- aux) -- (mat.east |- aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]